# Displaying result of XSLT using external CSS

Tags: css, xml, xslt

I have an XSL file and a CSS file, to display my XML, but I can't seem to get the CSS to take effect and not sure why it won't display with the CSS, is just showing all text normally.

```
h1
{
    background-color:black;
    color:#A901DB;
    text-align:center;
    padding:20px;
    float:center;
    width:1000px;
    font-family:"Lucida Sans Unicode";
}
```

XSL

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<xsl:stylesheet  xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" version="1.0">
<xsl:template match="/">
<html>
  <head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="BlogCSS.css"/>
  </head>

  <body>

  <xsl:apply-templates />

  </body>
  </html>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="blogPost">
  <p>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="blogTitle"/>  
  </p>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="blogTitle">
  <h1>
      <xsl:value-of select="."/>
      </h1>
          <br/>
      </xsl:template>
  </xsl:stylesheet>
```

XML file has the line  and it's displaying all the information in the XML file it's just not applying the CSS too it.

Thanks.

Comment: Which browser are you using? the css file is in the same folder as the result of the transformation?

Comment: What happens if you include the CSS in the XSLT stylesheet, inside the html output?

Comment: Tried in Chrome, IE and Firefox, all files are in the same place - can get others to work. putting the CSS in the <head> tags if I was doing internal doesn't have any effect either

Answer (score 1):

Use the XHTML namespace in the top level tag:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0"
            xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
            xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
            >
```